# How to install Tesseract 5.0.0 alpha on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, tesseract, python-tesseract

I downloaded tesseract on my MacBook using

`brew install tesseract-lang`.

However, it downloaded version 4.1.1. How do I download version 5.0.0 Alpha?
(I guess it is because 5.0.0 Alpha is still in developer phase. But if you know any way to download it, then that would be appreciated.)

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

This page is ranking highly in Google search results for 'install tesseract mac', so here is how you install tesseract for Mac in general:

```
brew install tesseract
```

You may also wish to accompany tesseract with a popular Python library: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Answer (score 1):

You probably will have to clone the repository and build it.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#macos

Comment: This one is again 4.1.1 and not 5.

Comment: Master branch is 5.0.0-alpha.

Comment: That is in Windows, not MacOS. Am I missing something? I am new to this, so if you could elaborate a little, that would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: It's not intuitive, so don't feel bad about it.  I wrote a Dockerfile last week that has all of the instructions you might need depending on your computer.  https://github.com/freelawproject/tesseract-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Dockerfile @flooie, it is very helpful if you need a more recent version than tesseract 4.0